# Google App Engine Java Backend app version

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm new to GAE Java backends and I'm unsure how backends relate to the application versions. I have read the GAE documentation and searched a lot and found nothing that would help.

My questions are:

How is the application version running in the backend selected from the deployed versions? Is it selected exactly like in the frontend, i.e. new backend instances use the default version by default?

If it is so, then what does command `appcfg backends  update [backend]` update exactly? Just the configuration files?

I really think this should be made more clear in the GAE docs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backends do not have versions:

1. You can select default version for frontend instances in Admin console, but you can not do this for backends.
2. Changing default version of frontend instances does nothing for backend instances.
3. Backends only have one version - the latest updated via `appcfg`.

So when you change code that affects both frontend and backend instances, you need to upload it twice.

Comment: This clarifies things. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, existing backends are shut down when you update the code.